# How to disable maximize button in delphi program?

Tags: delphi, button, maximize

How to disable maximize button in delphi program?

Answer (score 27):

Oh! I found in object inspector "BorderIcons"
Just set there biMaximize from true to false!

Comment: You are a genius!

Answer (score 3):

Here is another trick if you want to do it using code only.

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  l: DWORD;
begin

  // hide minimize and maximise buttons
  l := GetWindowLong(Self.Handle, GWL_STYLE);
  l := l and not(WS_MINIMIZEBOX);
  l := l and not(WS_MAXIMIZEBOX);
  l := SetWindowLong(Self.Handle, GWL_STYLE, l);

end;
```

Comment: In VCL code this should simply be `BorderIcons := BorderIcons - [biMaximize]`.

Answer (score 1):

BorderIcons := BorderIcons - [biMaximize]